# Make a symbol like a tilde "~" signal a carriage return in a large text file through Regex

Tags: regex, text

Essentially this is just a big blob of a textfile in which the tilde is supposed to signal a carriage return. Is there a way to craft a regex in which every occurrence of the tilde equals a \r?

I believe the general question should suffice. Providing code might be a HIPAA violation. I hope you understand that I'd rather not risk that.

Comment: You want to replace all instances of `~` with `\r`? Which language are you working in?

Comment: May you provide examples of inputs and respective outputs?

Comment: why do you want to replace every tilde with a carriage ? also notice "newline" is represented differently across platforms(if I recall `\n` on linux, `\r` on Mac, `\r\n` on Windows)

Comment: By the way, this return would be immediately AFTER each occurrence of the tilde. I apologize for not being clear on that.

Comment: Well, it's not that I want to literally replace the tilde symbol with the \r. I just want to make the tilde symbol signal a carriage return to the text immediately after the occurrence of a tilde. Sorry I didn't get back to you guys immediately. I didn't expect so quick a response. Thank you all!

Comment: @horcrux, I didn't have it at the time but I can post an partially encrypted example. Give me just a moment.

Comment: @horcrux No, I'm sorry. I can't provide that as it turns out. Simply put, just picture a large blob of text that's barely human readable. But whenever a "~" appears, I want that to signal the text editor (which I'm running in Windows but is just a .txt) to carriage return to a new line and resume until after the next "~".

Comment: I still cannot understand: do you want just to replace `~` with `~\r`?

Comment: @aryamccarthy, it's not really a language. It's just a flat file. I only need to run the regex to get it to do a carriage return.

Comment: This might help. As the expression does a check throughout the document, when it happens upon a "~", it should then do a return and start a new line until the next "~" and the next "~" and so on and so forth. I don't need to replace any characters. I just need it to do a return (new line) following the occurrence of a "~".

Comment: I just tried this after importing the file to a Linux system just a second ago and it worked great:

Comment: Let me try this again. I just tried this after importing the file to a Linux computer a second ago and it worked great:  Unix line endings:

neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ tr '~' '\n' < file                                                                           But is there a way to do this without actually deleting the '~'?

Comment: Although the answers on here are functional, it's not doing exactly what I was expecting. The newline is being added, which is great, but it's also getting rid of the tilde. Does anyone know a way I can do this and not lose the character? I've been all over the place trying to find an answer to this and coming up with nothing. And yes, I'm aware that a tilde is just a character. I get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you literally just want to do a plain substitution of these characters, you can just use something like `tr` (which is what it looks like you want from your response to comments).

You don't need to craft a regex to achieve this though.

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat file
some text~and the next line~third line
```

Mac line endings (as per your original post):

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ tr '~' '\r' < file
third linext line
```

Unix line endings:

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ tr '~' '\n' < file
some text
and the next line
third line
```

Windows line endings:

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ sed 's/~/\r\n/g' < file
some text
and the next line
third line
```

Comment: I just tried this in Linux and it worked beautifully:

Comment: If it answered your question, you should mark the checkbox beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't believe this escaped me but I tried this:

+
FIND:  ~
REPACE WITH: ~\n

And it worked. Much to my chagrin.

So I get the big, fat DUH! award. Sorry for the trouble, guys.